# Is there any algorithms/models to generate embedings of sequential data (other than RNN)?

Tags: neural-networks, model, algorithms, recurrent-neural-network, triplet-loss

I know that RNN can be used for such task. For instance facenet used rnn with triplet loss. But maybe there are some less sophisticated alternatives to try first?

Comment: BERT/transformer/XLNet with position embedding can handle encoding sequential data, and you can also try CNN(for instance the encoder of [FairSeq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq)).

Comment: bert is also based on rnn. And CNN is far from "less sophisticated alternative". I thought that there is some algo from pre-NN era, but it looks like that there is none.

Comment: What do you mean by "bert is also based on RNN"?